# Dynamic Port Forwarding for Publisher-Subscriber Architecture (Robot Operating System ROS2)

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding

My current network looks like the following Network Architecture:

[image: Network Architecture]

And all devices run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. There exist 2 Networks red (Raspberry's wlan0) and green (Raspberry's eth0). Only the Raspberry is member of both. On all devices run [ROS](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/) Nodes, which is essentially [Publisher-Subscriber architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) software.
Any node in this software uses Network ports to communicate, according to [this pattern](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Concepts/About-Domain-ID.html), i.e. the used ports are not fixed.
Let us assume we only use Domain 1, i.e. the pattern is:

- Port 7650 and 7651 for multicast
- Port pairs (7660|7661), (7662|7663) ... (7898|7899) are used for any new node

What I have so far is on Raspberry's [Crontab](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/crontab-in-linux-with-examples/) (runs on Boot) to be able to SSH Desktop -> Jetson:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Based on  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37554/local-network-between-two-rpis

# First we disable autoconfigured network on the Pi
# based on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/how-can-i-disable-autoconfigured-networking-on-raspbian    
sudo ip link set eth0 up
sudo ip addr add 10.66.66.1/24 dev eth0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT


# Forward Port 9001 from Raspberry to Jetson port 22
# to ssh onto the Jetson, now use:
# ssh jetson@RaspberryIP -p 9001
echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/forwarding
echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0 --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2:22
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.66.66.2 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

How would I update the script to forward (Jetson/Raspberry)-green network ports 7650 and 7651 for multicast into the (Desktop/Raspberry)-red network ports 7650 and 7651? How would I update the script to safely forward the used ports (Jetson/Raspberry)-green network to (Desktop/Raspberry)-red network?

I think I might be ok (for not too many nodes to avoid collision) to forward green->red:

- (7650|7651) -> (7650|7651)
- (7660|7661) -> (7898|7899)
- (7662|7663) -> (7896|7897)
- ...

which would essentially half my available nodes in one domain. *Edit: might not work, since Multi-Cast is the info which ports are used(?), re-mapping would render this info useless.* But this is definitely the end of my network voodoo. Help would be greatly appreciated.